# SQL query to get sum of averages

Tags: sql

Need to SQL QUERY to get following result

Consider Table

```
 Column1  || Column2 || Column3
    H1       A1          10
    H1       A1          10
    H1       A2          30
    H1       A2          30
    H1       A2          30
```

I want query to find Sum of Column1 for the averages of column2

Example

```
  Column1 || Column 3
      H1      40            (Average of A1 + A2 i.e (10 + 30)
```

Comment: Could you provide in tags which DB Engine you use?

Comment: "Average" or "sum"?

Comment: No H2 rows in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column1, SUM(Avg_col3) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT column1, column2, AVG(column3) AS avg_col3
    FROM t
    GROUP BY column1, column2
) A
GROUP BY column1;
```

Comment: Virtually identical to what I posted 5 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Tim - Yes you are correct. Realized it after posting. Since yours was the first it should have been accepted ideally. You want me to delete my answer ?

Comment: No worries, keep it `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You may do this via two aggregations:

```
SELECT Column1, SUM(Column3Avg) AS Column3
FROM
(
    SELECT Column1, Column2, AVG(Column3) AS Column3Avg
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2
) t
GROUP BY
    Column1;
```

This approach first aggregates by both the first and second column, to generate an intermediate result looking like:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3Avg
H1      | A1      | 10
H1      | A2      | 30
```

Then, we aggregate the above by the first column alone, and sum the column 3 averages.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model looks really messed up, if you have numbers repeating like this.  I would suggest:

```
select column1, sum(column3)
from (select distinct column1, column2, column3
      from t
     ) t
group by column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL Server` use following query to get desired result.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  Column1,
            AVG(Column3) AS Column3
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2
)
SELECT Column1, SUM(Column3) AS Column3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below code. You will get your result.

```
Select *
into #tmp
from (
    select 'h1' as Column1, 'A1' as Column2, 10 as Column3
    union all
    select 'h1' as Column1, 'A1' as Column2, 10 as Column3
    union all
    select 'h1' as Column1, 'A2' as Column2, 30 as Column3
    union all
    select 'h1' as Column1, 'A2' as Column2, 30 as Column3
    union all
    select 'h1' as Column1, 'A2' as Column2, 30 as Column3
)r
select * from #tmp
Select r.Column1, sum(r.Column3) Column3
from (
    select Column1, Column2, avg(Column3) Column3
    from #tmp
    group by Column1, Column2
 )r
 group by r.Column1
```